# Webserver on the fly decrypting?

Tags: php, security, apache, encryption, webserver

I am dealing with a concept for a project that involes absolutely critical data.

The most important part is that it needs to be stored encrypted.

An encrypted file system that is mounted from which the webserver serves the files is not enough.

The key to decrypt the data should be passed in the request URI on a secured connection along with a hash and a timestamp.

The hash, based on timestamp, key and filename validates the URI and stores it on a list, so it can only be accessed once.

The important part now is that the webserver should take the file from the disk, and serve it decrypted using they key he got from the request URI.

It should also be efficient and fast. This also requires an encryption method that does not require the whole file to be scanned. so that the file can progressively be decrypted. I think AES can do this with specified block sizes that are encrypted atomic.

So one option would be reading the source file into a php script in chunks of some megs where i decrypt using aes and print the decrypted content. The script then forgets the previous data and continues with the next chunk until eof.

If aes doesnt support that i can just encrypt chunks of defined size of the file seperately, concatenate them and do it the same when serving the files. however i would like to stick to one standard that i dont have to re invent, so i can also use standard libraries to encrypt the files.

However this will be very inefficient.

Do you know of any apache/lighttpd/nginx module or some better method?

Comment: well... what about using `mcrypt_decrypt()`?  //EDIT: but don't know about performance issues ;-)

Comment: sure, if i do it in the script. but i would like the files using the webserver, not php output buffers....

Comment: Only solution I can think of now is to validate hash, timestamp in php and pass decoding to external application with http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: to me as well... but well then i can just do the decryptoing in php too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should open the file with nmap() and then encrypt the data on-the-fly as needed.

I don't see anything more appropriate for this than G-Wan (200 KB), which offers native C scripts **and** AES encryption (no external libraries needed even if C scripts can link with any existing library).

If you need to achieve the best possible performances, then this is the way to go.

Comment: very nice that looks like my way to go

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into PHP's Stream Filters ( http://php.net/stream.filters ); with a bit of glue code, you could make it read an encrypted file with the regular PHP file access functions, and it would be mostly transparent to existing code.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a PHP module that lets you decrypt the files chunk/block-wise, you can always pre-split the file into appropriate sized blocks and encrypt each seperately.

Of course, remember that even if you're only sending out small pieces of the plaintext at a time, there's still plenty of other places that this vulnerable data can be held - particularly in the web server's output buffers. Consider the extreme case of a large-ish file being downloaded by someone stuck on a 2400 baud modem. You may very well decrypt and queue the entire file before even the first chunk's been downloaded, leaving the entire file in the clear in a buffer somewhere.

Comment: true. and it looks like going with php is my only possibility, so i will do it this way.

Comment: Good point - use a javascript (for viewing) or a client-side decryption module as a last step in the chain, requiring something typed in? I assume HTTPS would also be used, which has the added benefit that HTTPS paths in servers and clients are hardened compared to regular HTTP, unless HTTPS caching has specifically been enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There's no off-the-shelf solution to provide what you require. And while you've provided a bit of information about the data will be retrieved, you've not given much clues as to how the data will get on to the webserver in the first place.

You're jumping through lots of hoops to try to ensure that the data is not compromised - but if you're decrypting it on the server, then there is not only a risk of the data being compromised - but also that the key will be compromised. i.e. there's more theatre than substance in the architecture.

You seem to be flexible in the algorithm used for the encryption - which implies that you have some control over the architecture - so there is some scope to resolve these problems.

> The hash, based on timestamp, key and filename validates the URI and stores it on a list, so it can only be accessed once.

How does that ensure it is only accessed once? Certainly it could be used to reduce the window of opportunity for CSRF - but it does not eliminate it.

> The script then forgets the previous data and continues with the next chunk until eof.

This fundamentally undermines the objective of encryption - patterns within the data will still be apparent - and this provides a machanism for leveraging brute force attacks against the data - even if the block size is relatively large. Have a look at [the images here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) for a simple demonstration.

A far more secure approach would be to use CBC, and do the encryption/decryption on the client.

There are javascript implementations of several encryption algorthms (including AES) [this page](http://www.fourmilab.ch/javascrypt/) has a good toolkit. And with HTML5 / localstorage you can build a complete clientside app in HTML/javascript.

As you're starting to discover - just using a clever encryption algorithm does not make your application secure - it sounds like you need to go back and think about how you store and retrieve data before you worry about the method you use for encrypting it.

Comment: thanks for your concerns,+1. the main concern is for the server to get taken as a whole. it should be impossible to decrypt any data with it. thats why the client should pass the key in the link. the access list is just to avoid replay attacks if someone surfs over a compromised proxy or something. thats also a reason for https. of course only a client side solution will be really secure. i will consider that now. as well as the used encryption algorithm. i thought "seeking" was only possible with chunk wise encryption. will look into that a bit more.